# Как подключить socket_create()?

Tags: php, сервер, windows-server, azure, azure-websites

в общем на моем хостинге нельзя подключить socket_create() :

> К сожалению, включить socket_create() на виртуальном хостинге (shared-хостинге) нельзя из-за отдельных элементов, которые могут негативно повлиять на работу сервера в целом.
> Подобная установка возможна только на тарифных планах VPS

На VPS из-за этого я уходить не хочу, решил попробовать AZURE.
Создал сайт, выложил, и снова ошибка.

Нашел статью: [http://blogs.msdn.com/b/silverlining/archive/2012/09/17/using-custom-php-extensions-in-windows-azure-web-sites.aspx](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/silverlining/using-custom-php-extensions-in-windows-azure-web-sites)

Все сделал, как там описано:
[image]
[image]

php_sockets.dll взял из папки соответствующей версии php из openservera. Где все работает.

Соответственно тут phpinfo() и сама ошибка:
http://one-page.azurewebsites.net/action.php

Буду рад любой помощи. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Денис, проверьте, что версии PHP и расширения совпадают, расширение может быть скомпилировано для другой версии. Текущие загруженные расширения можно вывесли с помощью функции `get_loaded_extensions()`

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, функция говорит что сокеты не подключены. А расширений уже много перепробовал, без результата.

Comment: Их не нужно пробовать, вам нужно найти ID скопилированного PHP и по нему найти нужный dll, или вообще его скопилировать.

Comment: Я не знаю как и где его искать. На тостере посоветовали изучить `Configure Command ` и выбрать версию здесь - http://windows.php.net/download/
Я не понял как это сделать, и перебрал все по моей версии

Comment: Там нет вашей версии. Попробуйте http://windows.php.net/downloads/releases/archives/php-5.4.38-nts-Win32-VC9-x86.zip

Comment: Спасибо, это то что нужно, наконец-то заработало)